# np.ndarrayに変換できる条件がわかりません

Tags: python, numpy

リストをndarray形式に変換したいです。
下記にコードを載せています。

`a1_ndarray = np.array((a1,b))`ではエラーが出ませんが、`a2_ndarray = np.array((a2,b))`ではエラーが表示されます。
`ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.`

調べたところ変換元のリストが多次元のarrayに変換出来ない形であったり、要素数が異なるといった記事が出てくるのですが、ピンときておらず理解できません。
要素数が異なるといった場合には、それぞれの要素を確認したところエラーの起こった場合は一致しており、逆にエラーの起こらなかった場合に一致していません。

これらを理解するためには、どのような視点が抜け落ちていますでしょうか？
ご教授いただけますと幸いです

```py
import numpy as np 
import sys

print(sys.version) #3.6.7

a1 = [(3,4)]
a2 = [3,4]
b = [[2,5],[6,8]]
print(len(a1)) # 1
print(len(a2)) # 2
print(len(b)) # 2
a1_ndarray = np.array((a1,b))
a2_ndarray = np.array((a2,b))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1次元と2次元の配列(リスト)を合体させているので、どのようにつなげればいいのかわからないといった状態です。条件としては、同じ次元のデータにする必要があります。

また、a1_ndaarayの中身を見たところ、[list([(3, 4)]) list([[2, 5], [6, 8]])]となっていたので、配列の中にリストがある状態です。ですので、厳密には2次元の配列ではないように思われます。

一番簡単な合体はそのまま`a2_ndarray=a2+b`とするだけですが、構造を保ったままのリストとなります。

他には`np.append(a2,b)`を使うと合体させられますが、中身を全部一緒にしてしまうので1次元の配列としてまとめられてしまいます。

そのままの構造を保持したままがいいのであれば、

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(a2+b)
```

とすることもできます。この場合、DataFrame型にはなってしまいますが、Numpyとの相性はいいのでお勧めはします。

以上参考になれば幸いです。

Comment: >また、a1_ndaarayの中身を見たところ、[list([(3, 4)]) list([[2, 5], [6, 8]])]となっていたので、配列の中にリストがある状態です。ですので、厳密には2次元の配列ではないように思われます。
次元を確認したところ１次元になっていました。  


pandasはまだ触ったことながないので、教えていただきありがとうございます。  
見返して思ったのですが、numpy.arrayは行列式の配列を返す以上、そもそもその行列の中にリストを入れるといった使い方は本来しないものなのでしょうか？

Comment: そのような使い方（多次元配列）はよくされていると思います。ただ、次元が増えてくると[[[[[[数値]]]]]]みたいに[ ]の構造が増えて見づらいです。それに対し、データフレームはエクセルのシートのように表現でき、列や行に名前や通し番号を付けられます。そのため管理が楽です。

Comment: >numpy.arrayは行列式の配列を返す以上、そもそもその行列の中にリストを入れるといった使い方は本来しないものなのでしょうか？

もしかしたら認識が違っているかもしれません。僕の中で質問内容は「numpy.arrayに多次元配列を入れることはよくあることなのでしょうか？」といった内容でしたが、相違なかったでしょうか？

Comment: うまく伝えられなくてすみません。多次元配列（arrayの中にarrayを入れる）はよく使われます。例えば、x,y,zの3次元のデータを3Dのグラフで出力する場合は3次元の配列を使います。これはarrayの中にarrayがあり、さらにarrayが入って3重構造になっています。参照するときはPandasを使うと楽ですね。ちなみに、上記の[list([(3, 4)]) list([[2, 5], [6, 8]])]みたいなのは基本使わないと思います。配列型ではなくオブジェクト型扱いで、この場合構造も複雑になっています。

Comment: こちらこそ、誤解を生む文章となり申し訳ありません。>上記の[list([(3, 4)]) list([[2, 5], [6, 8]])]みたいなのは基本使わないと思います  やはりそうなんですね。
pandaは視覚的にも捉えやすくなるので、それぞれのメリットがありそうですね。
python使い始めて間もないため、初歩的な質問に答えていただきまして助かりました。

Comment: いえ、こちらこそ学習を深めることができるので助かっています。[list([(3, 4)]) list([[2, 5], [6, 8]])]が問題になっているのは、配列の中でlist()関数を使おうとしているところですね。私もどうしてこうなるのかは理解できていないのですが、違和感を感じます。同じ次元同士で合体させるか、Pandasを使うのが望ましいと思います。